# How do i get the link to a block?

Tags: block-editor

It appears that the latest gutenberg editor supports direct links to blocks added to a post as mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#anchor). How do I get the block link? I need to extract it programmatically but it's not saved in the post's markup as I've discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just an anchor link, so it will be the URL of the post plus the ID you gave it, preceded by a hash.